# Numpy: Check array for string data type

Tags: python, arrays, string

How can I determine if a Numpy array contains a string? The array `a` in

```
a = np.array('hi world')
```

has data type `dtype('|S8')`, where `8` refers to the number of characters in the string.

I don't see how regular expressions (such as `re.match('\|S\d+', a.dtype)`) would work here as the data type isn't simply `'|S8'`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
a.dtype.char == 'S'
```

or

```
a.dtype.type is np.string_
```

See [NumPy docs, Data type objects, Attributes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#attributes).

Comment: I noticed there's also a.dtype.kind == 'S'. Sweet!

Comment: Just a note: seems that this needs to be `a.dtype.type is np.str_` in Python 3.x

Comment: For Python 2.x _and_ 3.x you could test against `a.dtype.kind in {'U', 'S'}` to catch strings and unicode.

Comment: What happens if you put strings in an object array with character 'O'?

Comment: `a.dtype.type is np.string_ or a.dtype.type is np.str_` is a further alternative

Comment: But when you use pandas, strings can also appear as type 'object'...